# Why not write Prolog in one clause instead of two?

Tags: prolog

Sorry for the slightly vague title of this question, but I wasn't sure how better to phrase it.

I'm relearning Prolog after 35+ years, and am trying to understand what seems to be a convention. Imagine you were writing a predicate to test if an element were a member of a list. The common way to do this would be something like this...

```
list_member(X,[X|_]).
list_member(X,[_|TAIL]) :- list_member(X,TAIL).
```

You start off with a non-recursive version to handle the simple case, and then use a recursive one to continue.

As far as I can see, the following code does the exact same thing, but seems to me to be slightly more concise...

```
list_member(X, [H|T]) :- X=H; list_member(X, T).
```

Is there any reason why the first form is generally preferred over the second?

Comment: Would **readability** be a good answer?

Comment: It would be an excellent answer, except for the fact that I find the second version more readable. I realise this is subjective, but the more concise syntax seems easier to understand to me.

Comment: LOL. It is definitely subjective. I hate the `;` as it is too close to `,`.

Comment: I tend to go to great pains in placing parenthesis around the terms with a `;` to make it super clear what's going on. In general, it's neater to avoid it.

Comment: I guess the majority agree with you then, as I haven't seen any examples like the second snippet. Guess I should follow the crowd and not try and write code that others find less readable. Thanks

Comment: Not the best example  - rewritten for better determinism: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/lists.pl?show=src#member/2

Comment: @brebs I took the example from the book Seven Languages In Seven Weeks, which is what rekindled my interest in Prolog after so long. Not saying that makes it good code, just explaining where it came from. However, I'm curious about your comment. Please can you explain what you mean by "_better determinism_" (or point me to a source that explains it), as at my current stage (less than a week into Prolog) I haven't come across the term. Thanks

Comment: "Seven Languages In Seven Weeks" is a _really bad book_. The couple of languages I have used professionally are completely butchered in this book, like, you'd have to actively unlearn what is written there if you were to use the languages seriously. On the other hand, it got you excited about Prolog, so there is that.... Either way, there is a thing called indexing, and it usually happens only in the head, not in the body of predicates. Maybe doesn't matter for this specific example though.

Comment: @TA_intern I only bought the book as I got it really cheaply, and only used it to get an insight into some languages I hadn't seen. Prolog was the only one I actually took any further than simply reading the book, and I've since bought Clocksin & Mellish, which seems to be a very good book.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel Yes, I do realize it isn't nice to talk negatively, as I said, I am glad that the book got you interested in Prolog. I hope you find the language as useful and rewarding as I do.

Comment: [Both](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#member) are OK. But stick to a rigorous indentation to better distinguish `;` and `,`: comma at the end, semicolon at the beginning in a line.

Comment: @TA_intern I'm rekindling an old flame! QAs I said, I did some Prolog 35+ years ago, and really enjoyed it. I'm enjoying it just as much now, but with the benefit of 35+ years of software development behind me, so I can see how elegant it is for certain types of problems.

Comment: @false Thanks, I see what you mean. However, if the majority of people are using one style, I think I'd be better sticking to that. If nothing else, it will make my code easier to read when I post questions here!

Comment: NB. you've named your predicate `list_member` but you've put the arguments the other way around as `(member, list)`. I think when naming like that it's typical to have the name describe the arguments, i.e. in the same order.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Hmm, interesting point. I actually picked up that code from [a tutorial web site](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/prolog/prolog_lists.htm), so am not to blame! I actually think the name isn't that clear anyway, as it sounds like you want it to list the members, as opposed to checking if an element is in the list. Didn't think about that bit too much when posting, but it's  good point. Thanks

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel "*as it sounds like you want it to list the members, as opposed to checking if an element is in the list*" - it can be difficult to name things because the predicate can iterate members or check if an element is a member, depending how you call it. That's where the naming style `list_member` or `member_list` comes from, "predicate relating a list and its member(s)" rather than e.g. `memberOf` suggesting it can only be used one way, imperatively, to check if something is a member of a list.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Thanks for that, helps a lot. As it happens, I would be more likely to name it something like `element_is_in_list`, but then I'm still (re-)learning Prolog, so would probably prefer to spell things out.